# How to check for existence of a file which does not have a specific name? (In an iPhone cocoa app)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I am currently able to periodically monitor the existence of a particular file in a particular folder using NSTimer and NSFileManager. However, how will I go about checking the existence of a file as long as its title contains the text say, "MobileSafari", instead of the specific file name?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ***NSMetaDataQuery***. The predicate can use `@"kMDItemFSName contains[c] %@"` to find the files containing that string in their names. The searchScopes is an array of one or more strings with names of directories.

You should set up observer methods, i.e. register observers with `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` (in your class that launches the query) for the notifications `NSMetadataQueryGatheringProgressNotification` and `NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification`.

The former allows you to show the progress or to fetch the new results and display them. The latter indicates the query finished gathering, so you can stop the query and check [query resultCount] and [query results].

Comment: Will it work in a cocoa iPhone app? There seems to be only Mac OS X documentation for NSMetaDataQuery in the developer website.

Comment: Ouch. Sorry, forgot to look at the other tags. In that case, you'll have to get the files and subdirs using NSFileManager.

Comment: Its ok I found another way around my problem. Thanks for sharing!